# Pinia in VueRouter

Tags: vue.js, store, quasar-framework, pinia

I have some problems with a ***Pinia Store*** of ***Vue***, I log in and change the value of isLogin in the pinia store (true), and then it redirects me to the home page, but when I refresh the page, the router guard doesn't let me in. The console log prints false.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

***Log in and then redirect to the home page***

```
 ~ file: authGuard.js:5 ~ isAuth ~ isLogged: false auth.js:9 
 ~ file: auth.js:10 ~ setLoginValue ~ this.isLogged: false auth.js:11 
 ~ file: auth.js:10 ~ setLoginValue ~ this.isLogged: true authGuard.js:6 
 ~ file: authGuard.js:5 ~ isAuth ~ isLogged: true
```

***After refreshing the page, it returns me to the login page***

```
 ~ file: authGuard.js:5 ~ isAuth ~ isLogged: false
```

**authGuard.js**

```
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
import { useLogin } from "../stores/auth";

const isAuth = (to, from, next) => {
  const { isLogged } = storeToRefs(useLogin());
  console.log(" ~ file: authGuard.js:5 ~ isAuth ~ isLogged:", isLogged.value);
  isLogged.value ? next() : next({ name: "login" });
};

export default isAuth;
```

**auth.js (store)**

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

const useLogin = defineStore("login", {
  state: () => ({
    isLogged: false,
  }),
  actions: {
    setLoginValue() {
      console.log(" ~ file: auth.js:10 ~ setLoginValue ~ this.isLogged:", this.isLogged)
      this.isLogged = true;
      console.log(" ~ file: auth.js:10 ~ setLoginValue ~ this.isLogged:", this.isLogged)
    },
  },
});

export { useLogin };
```

**LoginLayout.vue**

```
<script setup>
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { useLogin } from "../stores/auth";

// Login Store
<script setup>
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { useLogin } from "../stores/auth";

// Login Store
const store = useLogin();
const { setLoginValue } = store;

const router = useRouter();

const callback = (_) => {
  setLoginValue();
  router.push({ name: "home" });
};
</script>
```

Comment: If the store isn't persistent, you can't expect the state to be restored on page refresh

Comment: you need to use localstorage or a plugin, e.g. https://github.com/prazdevs/pinia-plugin-persistedstate

Comment: Thank you, man. @yoduh, that plugin really helped me. Could you put it as an answer to mark it as solved?